# How to serialize object with vector of objects as attribute using boost::serialization

Tags: c++, object, serialization, boost, vector

I'm trying to create base of objects, which contains as attribute vector of object from different class. Here's my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
    #include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>

    using namespace std;

    class form_mesto
    {
    public:
        string mesto;
        int year;
        int mounth;
        int day;
        bool visit = false;
        form_mesto(string a_mesto)
        {
            mesto = a_mesto;
        }
    };

    class Place
    {
    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archieve>
        void serialize(Archieve&ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar& mestа;
            ar& person;
        }
    public:
        string person;
        vector<form_mesto> mestа;

        Place(string a_person)
        {
            person = a_person;
        }

        void add_place(form_mesto a_mesto)
        {
            mestа.push_back(a_mesto);
        }
    };

int main()
{
    string input_in_form = "London";
    string input_in_Place = "Eugene";
    form_mesto z = form_mesto(input_in_form);
    Place x = Place(input_in_Place);
    x.add_place(z);
    std::ofstream ofs("save.dat", std::ios::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa<<x;
};
```

Error, which i get is:

c:\boost_1_57_0\boost\serialization\access.hpp(118): error C2039: serialize: is not a member of "std::vector>".

Can somebody share experience of how to serialize that type of objects?

Comment: what does it mean to "serialize as attribute"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the code compilable, one has to do the following:

1. to include the header responsible for vector serialization

   ```
   #include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
   ```
2. to add the `serialize` method to the `form_mesto` class

   ```
   class form_mesto
   {
   private:
       friend class boost::serialization::access;
       template<class Archieve>
       void serialize(Archieve&ar, const unsigned int version)
       {
           // ...
       }
   // ...
   };
   ```

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbb6cd72e09bef9f) is the compilable code.